# Does anybody know how to change the Google Maps navigation arrows?

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I want to style the google maps navigation arrows, located in the top left corner of the map. Here is the picture of it:

[image]

Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to do with embed Google Map.
You need to create a map with javascript. Then you can disable controls and style the map.

Tutorial - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-disableUI
Styled Maps - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Hope it will help.